# Batch status - 'validating' after failed creation

Tags: shippo

Hi i`m tryng to work with shipping batches, after i create batch like this:

```
{"default_carrier_account":"9348***********50","default_servicelevel_token":"usps_priority","metadata":"test","label_filetype":"PDF_4x6","batch_shipments":[{"carrier_account":"93********************","servicelevel_token":"usps_priority","shipment":"c8c411c2ad8b497eb583decf7c3c614d","metadata":1},{"carrier_account":"9348ce6eecf**********ab850","servicelevel_token":"usps_priority","shipment":"768ae43826b04040b32490a6f069fa4f","metadata":2}]}
```

i get notification like this:

```
batch 0f0b69ae42bc475ab3c1421edddeb4fc creation failed
```

and after this i try to make api request and get batch data(status, messages, etc..) i did post request to : http://api.goshippo.com/batches/0f0b69ae42bc475ab3c1421edddeb4fc?page=1

and get response:

```
{
"object_id":"0f0b69ae42bc475ab3c1421edddeb4fc",
"object_owner":"info@skumatrix.com",
"status":"VALIDATING",
"object_created":"2017-04-16T16:35:24.925Z",
"object_updated":"2017-04-16T16:35:27.143Z",
"metadata":"test",
"default_carrier_account":"9***************b850",
"default_servicelevel_token":"usps_priority",
"label_filetype":"PDF_4x6",
"batch_shipments":{
"count":0,
"next":null,
"previous":null,
"results":{
}
},
"object_results":{
"purchase_succeeded":0,
"purchase_failed":0,
"creation_failed":0,
"creation_succeeded":0
},
"label_url":{
}
}
```

what i don`t understand is - why status is still validating and why there is no error messages ?

Comment: It appears that the error that is happening occurs before an update to the status of your Batch takes place. This appears to be leaving those Batch updates stuck with a status of `VALIDATING`.

Comment: This is because `VALIDATING` is the default status of a Batch object.

Comment: so whats wrong with my request, as i understand from support, its failed becouse i used shipping object id instead of shipping object array, but in api reference they wrote that i can use shipping object id or array...

Comment: That is because Batch endpoint, is intended to create those Shipments en masse. If you already have Shipment object ID's, then there is little more need to use the Batch endpoint. 

If you already have a bunch of Shipment object ID's, you could append them to an existing Batch using https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#batches-add-shipments. 

Otherwise, I would recommend just creating your labels using the desired rates associated with your Shipment objects.

Answer (score 0):

So, for starters, the default status of a Batch object in Shippo is `VALIDATING`. So this is why it would persist to stay in that state, although it might be a little confusing when there is an unexpected failure (which is what appears to have happened here).

As mentioned in the comments there, this failure occurred due to trying to do a Batch purchase using a collection of Shipment object_id's. The Batch endpoint is actually supposed to allow you to create a collection of Shipment objects en masse, and then later you can Batch purchase the labels for your desired rates on those Shipment objects.

Rate retrieval is generally the more time consuming process, depending on how many connected shipping accounts you have. So Batch creation is intended to allow you to have Shippo retrieve rates for a lot of packages and simply check on them once they are done (or get notified of their completion via Shippo's webhooks).

So moving forward, make sure that you first try to create the Batch with a collection of Shipments ([see here](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#batches-create)). Then you can proceed to create the labels for the shipment like [so](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#batches-purchase).